# kendo gridview and web api odata

Tags: gridview, kendo-ui, odata

Having issues feeding my kendo grid with my web api.  The call generates this:

```
/odata?$callback=jQuery19101822532636579126_1364840583015&%24inlinecount=allpages&%24format=json&%24top=20
```

but the response is:

```
The query parameter '$callback' is not supported.
```

Anyone has experience with this scenario?

```
 dataSource: {
               type: "odata",
               transport: {
               read: "odata/mydata"
              },
```

Comment: Found the answer here:
http://coderj.net/using-the-kendo-ui-grid-with-odata-on-wcf-data-services/#comment-76
and here
http://www.kendoui.com/blogs/teamblog/posts/12-10-25/using_kendo_ui_with_mvc4_webapi_odata_and_ef.aspx

Comment: You can find you answer here [MVC 4, Web API, OData, Entity Framework, Kendo UI, Grid, Datasource (CRUD) with MVVM](http://blog.longle.net/2013/06/17/mvc-4-kendo-ui-spa-with-layout-router-mvvm/).

Answer (score 3):

I managed to workaround this by setting both OData and JSON datatypes at different levels of the configuration

```js
dataSource: {
  type: "odata",
  transport: {
    read: {
      url: "/odata/FXDatas",
      dataType: "json"
    }
  }
},
```

Answer (score 1):

You have most probably configured to use JSONP instead of JSON, and you service does not support JSONP, since it requires manual implementation. Do not use JSONP, it is a work-around for cross-domain requests and has several limitations.